# Java 8 FilterOutputStream exception

Tags: java, io, try-with-resources

The was a change to the `FilterOutputStream.close()` method in Java 8 that is causing us some problems.  (See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/759aa847dcaf)

In previous versions of Java, the following code worked without throwing an exception.  However, under Java 8 we always get an exception when the try-with-resources mechanism closes the streams.

```
try( InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( inputStream );
     OutputStream outStream = payloadData.setBinaryStream( 0 );
     BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream( outStream );
     DeflaterOutputStream deflaterStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(
         bos, new Deflater( 3 ) ) )
{
    fileSize = IOUtil.copy( bis, deflaterStream );
}
```

The try-with-resources mechanism will first call `close()` on `deflaterStream`.  Since `deflaterStream` wraps `bos` which wraps `outStream`, `deflaterStream.close()` will call `bos.close()` which will call `outStream.close()` which closes the underlying stream to the database.

The try-with-resources mechanism will next call `close()` on `bos`.  Since `bos` extends `FilterOutputStream`, `flush()` will first be called on `outStream`.  However, since `outStream` is already closed, `outStream.flush()` throws exception: `java.sql.SQLException: Closed LOB`

```
caused by: java.io.IOException: Closed LOB
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobOutputStream.ensureOpen(OracleBlobOutputStream.java:265)
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobOutputStream.flush(OracleBlobOutputStream.java:167)
     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:141)
     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:158)
     at com.blah.uploadFile(CustomerUploadFacade.java:162)
     ... 38 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Closed LOB
     at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobOutputStream.ensureOpen(OracleBlobOutputStream.java:257)
     ... 42 more
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue?  If so how did you work around it?  Is there something wrong with the way we're using try-with-resources?

Comment: I assume `blobDeflaterStream` in the `try` body wants to be `deflaterStream `.

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right.  I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `FilterOutputStream`.  This implements [Closable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html).  The contract for this interface states:

> Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it. If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.

So calling `.close()` a second time should have no effect, but in this case it calls `flush()` which throws an exception.

FilterOutputStream is stuck in an inheritance hierarchy, so it's not easy to apply a fix at the point of the problem.

Failing to declare some of the streams as local variables in the `try` block will cause tools like FindBugs and Eclipse to flag the code as resource usage.  Diligent developers looking at this code later might think the same thing.

You could create a class, `CloseOnceBufferedOutputStream` which extends `BufferedOutputStream`.  It will have a `boolean` to remember if it has already been closed so it can meet the contract.  Override the `close()` method to check if the stream is already closed.  If so, just `return`.

If and when Oracle fix the underlying bug, your new class would be useless but the code would continue to work.

Comment: I agree that it's a bug.  I've submitted a bug report to Oracle and have been given Review ID JI-9014085.  I'll update this comment if I get a Bug ID.

Comment: This has been assigned Bug ID [JDK-8054565](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8054565)

Comment: A fix has been committed against that Bug ID for JDK 9: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/rev/5f22b23442ba  I don't believe it will be backported to JDK 8.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't declare `bos` and `outStream` in the `try` and so they won't be automatically closed. Only the declared `AutoClosable`s will be closed.

The JVM does not analyze the declared `AutoClosable`s whether one is constructed using another, so each of them must be closed explicitly. If their `close()` method can only be called once, that could lead to problems you're experiencing.

Only declare `deflaterStream` like this:

```
try( InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( inputStream );
     DeflaterOutputStream deflaterStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream( payloadData.setBinaryStream( 0 ) ),
            new Deflater( 3 ) ) )
{
    fileSize = IOUtil.copy( bis, deflaterStream );
}
```

**Edit:**

Following the comments here's how you could close the stream returned by `payloadData.setBinaryStream( 0 )` in case of some other issue:

```
OutputStream outStream = null;
try( InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( inputStream );
     DeflaterOutputStream deflaterStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream( outStream = payloadData.setBinaryStream( 0 ) ),
            new Deflater( 3 ) ) )
{
    fileSize = IOUtil.copy( bis, deflaterStream );
}
catch (ExceptionsYouWantToCatch eywtc)
{
    if (outStream != null) {
        // Here you have the chance to close it
        try { outStream.close(); } catch(IOException ie){}
    }
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that could lead to problems if an exception is thrown when creating the `BufferedOutputStream` or `DeflaterOutputStream`.  For example, if the creation of the `BufferedOutputStream` threw an `OutOfMemoryError`, the underlying BLOB stream couldn't be closed by the try-with-resources mechanism because it's not listed separately.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, of course. If the `BufferedInputStream` constructor would throw an exception, there would be no reference returned by the constructor to call the `close()` method on. But you can handle this by adding a `catch` branch to the `try` and close `inputstream` by yourself.

Comment: Oh, and if `BufferedOutputStream` constructor would throw an exception (as you asked), `bis.close()` would still be called (`bis` is already created at this point hence its `close()` method can and *will* be called).

Comment: My comment was about failing to close the stream created by `payloadData.setBinaryStream` rather than `bis`

Comment: Yes, that won't be closed. You can go around this by storing the returned stream in a variable of yours, and in the `catch` branch check it and close it yourself - if you need to.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow 100% - can you post a code sample?

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example for this.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, You shouldn't have to do this but...

You don't need to declare all output streams you create, instead you can just declare the outer most ones.

```
try( InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( inputStream );
     DeflaterOutputStream deflaterStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(
         new BufferedOutputStream( payloadData.setBinaryStream( 0 ) ), new Deflater( 3 ) ) )
{
    fileSize = IOUtil.copy( bis, blobDeflaterStream );
}
```

This way deflatorStream will be closed, which will close the others.

Comment: This is the same as icza's answer below - I'd be interested on your thoughts about the comment I left on that answer.

Comment: @Nathan If you get an `OutOfMemoryError` the default action should be to shutdown the JVM.  If you get something so critically wrong, a small resource leak is the least of your problems.

Comment: To my knowledge, the JVM doesn't have an option to exit when an `OutOfMemoryError` occurs (although it does have the heap dump option).  We've seen numerous cases where the system recovers after such an error (normally when one thread tries to create a very large local variable).  That being said, `OutOfMemoryError` was just an example - there could be other reasons why the creation of the wrapping stream fails.  We want the code to be as robust as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Our final solution was to fix the FilterOutputStream ourselves:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (!closed) {
        closed = true;
        try (OutputStream ostream = out) {
            flush();
        }
    }
}

private boolean closed = false;
```

This class was included in a small JAR file and added to the boot classpath: `-Xbootclasspath/p:%APP_HOME%\lib\jdkFix.jar`

Hopefully Oracle will acknowledge this issue is a bug and fix it in a future update of Java 8.

Comment: As per the comment on @WW.'s answer, I will probably need to keep my jdkFix.jar until JDK 9.